# Django admin select like permission field

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin

How to create form in admin panel like this one? It's default admin user view.

[image]

My looks like that, but i want two "windows"

[image]

```
class RoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', )

    fieldsets=(
        (None, {'fields': ('name', )}),
        (_('Role Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('permissions', ),
        }),
    )
```